# Getting ALL solutions of the logistic ODE with DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

In Mathematica 10.0, the command

```
DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]*(1 - y[x]), y[x], x]
```

gives

```
{{y[x] -> E^x/(E^x + E^C[1])}}
```

I take it the constant `C[1]` is assumed to be an arbitrary complex number, but I'm still missing the two solutions `y[x]->0` and `y[x]->1`. Is there a way to force Mathematica to produce all solutions?

Comment: You can take the limit `C[1]->Infinity` and `C[1]->0`, so those are particular cases of the general solution.

Comment: Those solutions are called [singular solutions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution) and `DSolve` does not find these. You can usually find them for first order ode's by letting the arbitrary constant tend to plus/minus infinity.

Comment: Chip, I don't think my two extra solutions are "singular" in the given sense; the logistic equation satisfies the assumptions of Picard-Lindelöf everywhere, so we have existence and uniqueness of solutions everywhere.

Comment: b.gatessucks: I would have to take `C[1]->-Infinity` to get the solution `y[x]->1`, but when dealing with the complex plane `-Infinity` and `Infinity` are the same thing.

Comment: @Axel You are right, thanks for pointing that out.